# solr update multiple tables from mysql database

Tags: mysql, solr, indexing

I am using solr 4.7. I indexed two tables from different mysql databases in solr with Dataimporthandler. For each table index I use different data-config.xml files, because I get a problem with the data_index_time during the update.

I make the update with a cronjob script. If something changes in the DB, than this script makes a solr update. If someone changes in two tables something, then solr should be updated both at the same time. But it didn't. I think the problem is because of the index time.

My dataconfig for each table:

```xml
<entity name="entry_data_846" datasource="tk_846" pk="id"
        query="SELECT * FROM prj_search_seso_cache
                        WHERE '${dataimporter.request.clean}' != 'false'
                              OR SIO_Lastupdate > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
        transformer="script:decodeHTMLEntities,TemplateTransformer,RegexTransformer">
```

Comment: It is not indexing at all or taking time to appear in result?

Comment: It is indexing for example the first table but the second dataimporthandler calls the request without updating changes.